# Question on Neumann-Zagier Symplectic matrix of an ideal triangulation of one cusped 3-manifold

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, character-varieties

For a knot complement $M\backslash K$ on a general closed 3-manifold $M$, the gluing equations are given by ($k$ is the number of ideal tetrahedra in an ideal triangulation of $M\backslash K$)

$c_I:=\prod_{i=1}^k z^{A_{Ii}}(1-z^{-1})^{B_{Ii}}=1$ ($I$-th internal edges)

$m=\prod_{i=1}^k z^{a_i}(1-z^{-1})^{b_i}$ (merdian variable)

where coefficients $\{A_{Ii},B_{Ii},a_i,b_i\}$ are all integers.

A solution to the equations give a representation $\textrm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(S^3\backslash K)\rightarrow PSL(2,C))$ where the boundary meridian cycle is mapped into a $PSL(2,C)=SL(2,C)/Z_2$ with eigenvalues $\pm \{m^{1/2}, m^{-1/2}\}$.

When $M=S^3$, as far as I know, all the integer coefficients $\{a_i,b_i\}$ for meridian variable can not be even
(while the integer coefficients $\{e_i,f_i\}$ for longitudinal cycle, $l=\prod_{i=1}^k z^{e_i}(1-z^{-1})^{f_i}$, can be always made even integers by redefining $l\rightarrow l \prod c_I^{n_I}$ with proper choice of integers $\{ n_I\}$) regardless of the choice of an ideal triangulation.

Question : Is there any simple topological criterion to determine whether the integer coefficients $\{a_i, b_i\}$ for the boundary meridian cycle of $M\backslash K$ can be made even or not (for given an ideal triangulation of $M\backslash K$)?